# What happens in Desert Island if no fate tokens are in play at the end of the round?

Tags: desert-island

In [Desert Island](http://gorillaboardgames.com/our-games/desert-island/), [the rules](http://www.siadek.com/dirules.pdf) state

> FATE  –  the  event  that  appears  the  most  happens  to  the  character(s)  with  the  most  fate  tokens

and

> Each week something bad happens to somebody. (Boar!, Illness, Monkeys,
>   Rats, Tsunami).The character (or characters if 2 or more are tied)
>   with the most total fate tokens on them and their location will be the
>   target.

If no players or locations with living players have any fate tokens at the end of the round, is no fate applied? Or does a the prevalent fate apply to all living characters?

**EDIT**

Having tried both approaches extensively, we now play with no fate tokens => no fate event.

If fate applies to a lone player every round, they die pretty fast. Players are more likely to sneakily sabotage each other if they think there's some hope of lighting the fire on their own... and sabotage is what makes this game fun!

Comment: In case of a tie, it happens to the characters with the most tokens. And if no character have tokens, they all have the most (even if it is none).

Comment: Well... mathematically this is true, but if the way it's written implies that some tokens exist. For example: `the most total fate tokens on them and their location` implies a non-zero quantity of tokens.

Comment: It's also important for the dynamic of the game, because if you play fate every round with only one person alive, they will die very quickly. If you play fate only when they have 1 or more fate tokens, they have a reasonable chance of lighting the fire alone.

Answer (score 3):

As the rules you quoted say, all characters with the highest number of tokens (in your case, zero) will get a bad event. "The highest number" is mathematically defined as "no number is higher than this". If the highest number is zero, then that's it.